# Printing all the data from a firebase DB in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a firebase DB that looks like this:

[image: like this]

I want to know how I can dynamically print every task in its own box with react even if more task are added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a .map function.  For example, check out this resource for the docs.  I think this is what you're asking for:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

the example below is a simple todo list.  I'm pulling the 'todos' object off this.props but that object can be substituted for however you're accessing the return object from firebase.

```
export class TodoList extends React.Component {
    render () {
      var {todos, showCompleted, searchText} = this.props;
      var filteredTodos = TodoAPI.filterTodos(todos, showCompleted, searchText);

      var renderTodos = () => {
        if (filteredTodos.length === 0){
          return (
            <p className="container__message">Nothing To Do</p>
          );
        }
        return filteredTodos.map((todo) => {
          return (
            <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo}/>
          )
        });
      };

      return (
        <div>
          {renderTodos()}
        </div>
      )
    }
  };

  export default connect(
    (state) => {
      return state;
    }
  )(TodoList);
```

In this example, I call 'renderTodos()' which first checks if there's any todos and if there is, it uses javascripts .map method to iterate through all the todos returning another component (the individual todos - each individual todo is a component) -- that component displays each todo item.  Hope that helps.

Comment: So it looks like the map just goes through every value in an array. How can i get the dynamically changing array for each of my values?

Comment: How are you accessing your firebase data?  Typically you'd pull the object off the props and that will contain your tasks with all their properties...when there's new data in firebase, the object you pulled off props will contain the new data

Comment: I actually followed this tutorial https://youtu.be/p4XTMvagQ2Q which is a pretty static way of getting my data. Is there guide or tutorial that can show me how to access the data like you said above?

Comment: hmmm sadly i still don't understand completely. I would be happy to pay you for your time in helping me if you're up for it.

Comment: i edited my answer for clarity.  Also check out the repo for my react todo project [here](https://github.com/jsw324/react-todo) I'm by no means a React expert, I just had a similar challenge with React so thought I could offer my experience.  Hope this helps!

Comment: oh thank you so much! I'm slowly getting it, the only thing that's stopping me are the first 2 vars at the top.

Comment: Those 2 variables are kind of irrelevant for your purposes.  If you look at the renderTodos() function, you can essentially substitute the filteredTodos variable for the object that contains your data.  If this helps, please mark the answer correct :)